# Limit o365 App to access specific OU or security group

Tags: azure, office365, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to limit the interaction of an app that is built on the o365 api to a specific set of users? I checked in Azure, but I don't see a setting that would do that. The permissions for the app indicate the they would give it access to the entire directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only scopes that are supported (when providing access to O365 APIs, Azure AD Graph or Microsoft Graph) are for the signed-in user only and tenant-wide. Unfortunately we don't have anything in-between.  This is something that we are considering.  Please file a request for this on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).  It would also be great to understand the scenario or reason for this request.